# Convert an Option[Validation[E, A]] to a Validation[E, Option[A]]

Tags: scala, validation, scalaz

In ScalaZ, what is the idiomatic way to convert an `Option[Validation[E, A]]` to a `Validation[E, Option[A]]`?

For example, in the following hypothetical code:

```
def convert(x: Option[Validation[E, A]]): Validation[E, Option[A]] =    
  /* ??? */

def validateThing(thing: A): Validation[E, A] = 
  /* whatever */

def exampleUseCase(maybeThing: Option[Thing]): Validation[E, Option[Thing]] = {
  val validated: Option[Validation[E, Thing]] = a.map(validateThing(_))

   // ...

  val result: Validation[E, Option[Thing]] = convert(validated)
  result 
}
```

what would the implementation of `convert` look like in idiomatic ScalaZ?

Comment: I would say that this convertion doesn't make much sense to me. What result would you expect if `maybeThing` is `None`? Probably failed validation, that it's none, if it's not none then you can extract value and put if  as a `successful` case, then you don't need `Option`.

Comment: `validate` and `validateThing` are hypothetical, just to show the context of where such a conversion *might* take place.  I am only interested in what the implementation of `convert` would be.

Comment: But to answer the specific question of what to expect when `maybeThing` is `None`:  a successful validation of `None`.

Comment: @4lex1v Why assume None is invalid? Imagine a field that is supposed to be a optional date for example, "AAA" would be invalid data, "1/1/2000" would be a filled date, "" would be an empty date.

Comment: @scrapdog, didn't check the API, but what you need is probably the method `sequence`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see two possible solutions here. Probably the easiest one using pattern matching on the argument, example:

```
def convert[A](v: Option[Validation[Throwable, A]]): Validation[Throwable, Option[A]] = {
  v match {
    case None => Validation.success(None)
    case Some(valid) => valid.map(Some(_))
  }
}
```

For Scalaz based solution, i was thinking about [sequence](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Traverse.scala#L100), this way you need to use [ValidationNel](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/package.scala#L209) instead of Validation, to aggregate possible issues, the you can implement `convert` with `Traversable`:

```
def convert[A](v: Option[ValidationNel[Throwable, A]]): ValidationNel[Throwable, Option[A]] = 
  Traverse[Option].sequenceU(v)
```

Please note that in fact i'm using `sequenceU` instead of just `sequence`, it's nothing more than internal Scalaz magic for proper type inference, cause Validation has two type parameters. Hope it helps

Comment: You can just write `c.sequenceU` if you've imported everything or at least `std.option._` and `syntax.traverse._`.